# Bootstrap CSS bg-success alert not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

For some reason bg-danger class in Bootstrap 3 does not display red background. Why?

```
<p class="bg-danger">There was an error updating your details.</p>
```

Comment: what color does it display? DO you have a link?

Comment: Just white background

Comment: You probably already tried this but...did you try adding  !important to the background-color

Comment: Adding it where? I don't think the solution is to edit bootstrap's code

Comment: no, never edit bootstrap, you'll need it virgin. Make a separate custom.css and declare it right below the bootstrap.css in th ehead so that it overrides the bootstrap.css Add the new style attribute there.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

In Bootstrap you have the following pre-defined backgrounds:

**Bootstrap 3.1.0:**

```
<div class="bg-primary">...</div>
<div class="bg-success">...</div>
<div class="bg-info">...</div>
<div class="bg-warning">...</div>
<div class="bg-danger">...</div>
```

**Bootstrap 3.0.3:**

```
<div class="alert alert-success">...</div>
<div class="alert alert-info">...</div>
<div class="alert alert-warning">...</div>
<div class="alert alert-danger">...</div>
```

**Bootstrap components**

> **[View all Bootstrap components here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts)**

Answer (score 16):

Contextual backgrounds `bg-primary`, `bg-success`, `bg-info`, `bg-warning` and `bg-danger` were added to Bootstrap as of version 3.1.0 and were not present in 3.0.3 and before.

There have however been `alert`s with the four contextual classes `alert-success`, `alert-info`, `alert-warning` and `alert-danger` which are suitable for that kind of error messages.

```
<p class="alert alert-danger">There was an error updating your details.</p>
```

Also see the Bootstrap Alerts Component: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts

Comment: +1 I was having trouble with `bg-danger` on a `form-control` because the latter overwrites the former's colour. Searching led me here and prompted me to try `alert-danger` which overwrites `form-control` and therefore works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

I just spent all day trying to figure out why `alert-error` wasn't working, only to realize it's not alert-error, it's alert-*danger*. Leaving this here in case someone else tortures themselves for hours trying to figure out what's wrong with their Bootstrap 3 alert.